# All OSM points/polygons with address string

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

How do you list all the polygons and points in qGIS in such way their full address shows up. My understanding is that an address is always constructed by looking at the 'building's or POI's adjacent street or building exit.

Is there such a tool that was already designed with this use case in mind, to ingest the polygons while constructing their addresses (and possibly multiple addresses for the same location)?

I would like to avoid the Overpass API and do this preferably on-fly during the ingestion phase via osm2pgsql.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would find a definition of what is a valid address from OSM data for your purposes.

IMHO an OSM object needs at least the two keys `addr:street=xxx` and `addr:housenumber=yyy`.

See the OSM wiki about [Addresses](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) to find out more details

For example in OSM data for Germany we have complete boundary relations for places down to admin_level=8 and also for all postalcode areas.

Thus there is theoretical no need for the other tags like `addr:city` or `addr:postcode` ... but you have to find out what is the OSM data situation in your target country to define in what place / city a unique street is located.

Fot testing purposes, I strongly recommend to get familiar with overpass-API or the related user interface [overpass-turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) so that you can be sure about your complete search parameters.

When you have tested this, convert your overpass query to any OSM database connected to QGIS.

Or try the [QuickOSM plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) for QGIS to have an easy import of raw OSM data into QGIS via overpass-API.

Comment: `addr:street` is not mandatory, if the building or POI is part of an `associated street` relation.